# In Go when using the Example... testing method is there a way to have it show a diff instead of got... want...?

Tags: testing, go

I've been using go for a bigger project and love it, and for my testing i've been using the

```
func ExampleXxx {
    ... code ...
    //Output:
    //...expected output ...
}
```

method for testing. When it fails it will say

```
got:
... bunch of lines showing the output of test ...
want:
... the comment you put in to show what you expected ...
```

is there any way to make it show just the difference? I can take the two and copy to separate files and run a diff etc, but I'd much rather just have it show the parts that were wrong as some of my tests have longer output.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I'm using http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Examples and want the output to show a diff not the current output. I know I can do the diff manually.

Comment: did you search at all? Both github.com/mb0/diff and github.com/kylelemons/godebug/diff look like likely candidates. (hint, use godoc.org)

Comment: did you read my question at all? I'm not talking about a diff package ... i'm talking about the results of http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Examples

Comment: Ok, but testing Examples don't produce diffs, so if you want a diff you'll need a tool to do that.

Comment: Thats essentially what my question is, whether there is a way to natively do a diff or if I'll have to use something to process the output to produce the diff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot do this. This is not the intended use of Examples.

Examples are a nice way to show how some function will behave: Examples exists to document. The main reason for validating the example output is to make sure the Examples are valid/correct, not that your code is okay. For the later you have Test functions

Most often the output of an Example displays input and output (or just output) of one invocation of a certain function/method per line; sometimes Examples use the different lines to show parts of a complex result, e.g. one line per element of the returned slice.

I think your use of Examples to "verify the flow of my program" contradicts the intention of Examples. I would use Test functions and use any of the available diff tools to generate a got, want, diff output myself if I'd like to test e.g. a text processor on large bunches of input.

Comment: While I agree what what you've said, it still would be nice to be able to have a diff output instead. The way that examples work fits perfectly for how I am developing my project and thats why I used them. If there was something that would just verify the output of function like ExampleXxx's yet provide different ways to view the results that would be amazing!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, it sounds like [GoConvey](http://goconvey.co/) would do the trick... It's a TDD tool that runs in the browser, and it will show you colored diffs for most failures:

[image: GoConvey failure]

You can use it with your existing tests; if you don't want to convert to the GoConvey DSL, that's okay. You don't have to be using a TDD workflow *per-se* in order for it to work, but if you can run `go test`, this tool should be able to pick it up. (I've never used the Example functions for testing... I'm not sure what you mean by that, honestly.)

(There's a new web UI in the works that will still show the diff. See below.)

[image: GoConvey new UI]

These are contrived examples, but obviously the diff is more useful with longer output.

Is that kind of what you're looking for?

Comment: I'll look at this tonight and if it works i'll mark this as the correct answer tomorrow. From the screen shots this looks really helpful!

Comment: unfortunately not what I was hoping however I am considering switching to using this. Thank you for showing it to me.

Answer (score 0):

From the style guide: https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/Style#Useful_Test_Failures

```
if got != tt.want {
     t.Errorf("Foo(%q) = %d; want %d", tt.in, got, tt.want)    // or Fatalf, if test can't test anything more past this point
}
```

This will put out only errors of course.  There is nothing built into go that lets you show the diff.  I think just piping this to whatever diff tool you are using against your last output would still be best.

Go is great, but no reason to re-invent tools that already do fantastic jobs that already exists at the terminal.

Comment: I'm using this http://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Examples not "normal" TestXxx method

Comment: I guess I'm somewhat confused as to the scenario in which you need to diff regardless.  Typical test suites either pass/fail.  TDD in general is all about coverage that passes/fails, and then investigate the failed package.  How that matters from one test pass to the next is irrelevant.

Comment: when using example functions it will output when the example was outputted followed by when was expected automagically (see the link i posted) I would like that to be diff instead EVERYTHING ... to help identify why the example failed (PS i'm not following TDD exactly)

Comment: Wow, I shouldn't write in a rush ... with ExampleXxx tests that fail it shows what was received and what it expected, instead I would like to see a diff of the two so that I can identify where my test went wrong. I'm not using TDD, instead I use ExampleXxx tests to verify the flow of my program as which is more important to me then pure TDD.